# WF4 : where are Finished persisted state machines?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, state-machine

I have successfuly saved the state machine and applied bookmarks to state machine after loading them for mutiple times.

But what happens when they reach to a final state ?

Why they are removed from persitance data store (**[System.Activities.DurableInstancing].[InstancesTable]**) after geting finished?

Is that normal or am I makeing a mistake in persisting finished statemachines ?

Comment: Why would you need that?

Comment: @Will : I want to know that is it a normal behaviour or I missed something. Why no one mentioned that "finished workflows will be removed from the persistance database" in books or internet articles ?

Comment: Why would they not?  They are done executing.  What value comes by storing the completed workflow?  The same as variables collected after their scope is complete.

Comment: @Will Ok I understood. But in approval systems we have to know that who are the people who approved this document up to now. So the best way to implement approval systems is that we keep the triggred bookmark up to now and don't persist the workflow, and whenever we want to know where is this document now in our approval system, create a new instance of workflow and apply the bookmarks up to now and understand in which state we are.

Comment: Workflow is code.  If *any* method determined approval/denial, you wouldn't store the code of that method, you'd store who approved, who denied, and the final state.  So you shouldn't be storing the code of the workflow but the results.  I would be using custom activities extending NativeActivity, and using a workflow extension to communicate outside when someone approves/denies.  When the workflow completes, I record that result as well.

Comment: @Will Ok thank you very much for the hint. I think I got the hang of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workflow is code.  You define the logic using larger pieces, but it executes and returns a result. It is *not the result itself.*

Imagine you had a class that had methods you call that determines approval/denial.  You would spin up that class, pass in argument values, and let the code execution determine approval/denial.  What do you do after this code executes?

You wouldn't store the code of that method, that's for sure.  You would store who approved, who denied, and the final result.

So you shouldn't be storing the *code* of the workflow **but the results**.

I would accomplish the goals of this workflow by creating custom Activities extending [NativeActivity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.nativeactivity.aspx), using one or more [workflow extensions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tilovell/archive/2010/06/08/wf4-workflow-4-0-hosting-extensions.aspx) to communicate with the outside world to send notifications about approval or denials waiting for action. Along the way I'd record who did what when my bookmarks resume execution.  When the workflow completes, I record the final result as well.

Comment: Yes you are right, I wanted to put all the burden on workflow!